# Is this motion rotation or curvelinear translation?

Tags: kinematics, reference-frames, terminology, definition, rotational-kinematics

Arrow orbit around point C like graph show.

Is motion of arrow, rotation or curvelinear translation according to physics definition?

What is definition and types of translation and rotation?

I find this:

> *"When the paths of motion for any two points on the body are parallel lines, the motion is called rectilinear translation. If the paths of motion are along curved lines which are equidistant, the motion is called curvilinear translation"*

[image]

Comment: This might help - [Axis of rotation of a spool unwinding and falling under gravity](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/780490/37364)

Comment: Is the sidereal motion fixed, i.e. the arrow always pointing to the same part of the sky?

Comment: @JohnAlexiou yes arrow point always up

Comment: Is this a trolling question? what are you asking for? the arrow describes a circle, then is curve linear motion

Answer (score -2):

If the arrow rotated clockwise just about the circle centre, C, it would point radially outwards as it went round the circular path. If it *also* rotates anticlockwise, with the same periodic time, about its own centre, then it will retain a fixed orientation, as shown in the diagram. Two rotations (which we could call *orbiting* and *spinning*) and no translation.

Comment: I read that exist rectilinear translation and curvelinear translation...

Comment: That's no doubt correct. [Would you, for example, regard my rotation about C as a curvilinear translation?] I'd guess that there's more than one way of analysing the motion. Mine is not very sophisticated! Let's hope that you get a more useful answer.

Comment: No, if arrow change orientation then this is rotation. I observe arrow from inertial frame

Comment: Instead of saying "my rotation about C" I should have said "my dual rotation". I think that this avoids your objection, as the arrow maintains its orientation.

Comment: I disagree with this, the arrow is being translated along the circular path of its orbit. It is not rotating within its own reference frame. If its tip pointed radially outward always, it would change orientation, which would require a rotation.

Comment: I feel like my last comment was poorly worded. What I mean to say is that the object is orbiting, but if this orbital motion is subtracted out there is no second rotation because the arrow's orientation is not changing. Pointing radially outwards would in fact require a second rotation.

Comment: "the object is orbiting, but if this orbital motion is subtracted out there is no second rotation because the arrow's orientation is not changing." No indeed, but the second rotation (spin) is needed when the first rotation (orbiting) is NOT subtracted out.

Comment: @PhilipWood No second rotation is needed. If a gyroscope were taken from rest and moved in a circular orbital path as depicted in the image, its spin axis would remain unaltered. What would cause the rotation of this axis? There would be no torque to induce such rotation since a gyroscope is specifically constructed so that motion of the outer housing does not affect the spin axis. The gyroscope's axis is analogous to the arrow in the picture.